# How do I implement this to the expectedArrivalFrom and expectedArrivalUntil?

Tags: javascript, parcel

How do I implement this to the expectedArrivalFrom and expectedArrivalUntil? I want "expectedArrivalFrom" todays date and I want "expectedArrivalUntil" seven days from today

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/parcel-delivery#parcel_delivery_with_shipping_information

```
     var d = new Date();
     var today = document.write('Today is: ' + d.toLocaleString());
     d.setDate(d.getDate() + 5);
     var sevenDays = document.write('<br>7 days FROM NOW: ' + d.toLocaleString());
```